# Not able to show block after hiding it through toggle on a different media size

Tags: jquery, html

I am not a pro at html5 but this what I am trying

I am developing this responsive layout where I am using a toggle to hide and show the left nav of smaller device. It works fine when I am first clicking the trigger [+] from the top nav. But when I am hiding it by clicking the [+] and changing the orientation of the screen I cant show the left nav any more. Any suggestion how to tackle it? For the toggle I am doing a very simple JQuery toggle which looks like this

```
var topNavInteractive = $('section nav.navLeft ul');

    $('.dropDownTrigger').click(function(){
        topNavInteractive.slideToggle();
    })
```

Here is the working prototype
http://soumghosh.com/otherProjects/beamtous/

Comment: pls show html also ...!!

Answer (score 0):

This will work ..!!

## **jQuery**

```
var topNavInteractive = $('.navLeft');

$('.dropDownTrigger').click(function () {
    topNavInteractive.slideToggle();
});
```

Working Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/UsTMG/

Comment: what exactly did you change in it? Looks same to me. Just curious

Comment: changed var topNavInteractive = $('section nav.navLeft ul'); to var topNavInteractive = $('.navLeft'); 
:)